# Componentwise convergence for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Show that for the sequence $x_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the following holds true $$\lim_{k\to\infty} x_k=a$$ if and only if for every $i \in \mathbb{N}$ $$\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{k,_j}=a_j$$ where $x_k=(x_{k,_1},\dots x_{k,n)}, a=(a_1 ,\dots, a_n)$

This is essentially just the Componentwise Convergence Criterion for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ right? I cannot find any proof for this online except something where the writer requires the reader to know some topological properites which I haven't gone to yet. If anyone knows where I could find one I would gladly appreciate a link.

Comment: The proof is rather obvious ! Why don't you try to prove it ?

Comment: I've tried something using Cauchy-Schwartz, but cannot seem to get anywhere...

Comment: See my answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I denote $\|\cdot \|_1$ the $1-$norm in $\mathbb R^n$, i.e. $$\|x\|_1=|x_1|+...+|x_n|.$$

---

Suppose $(x_n)$ converges. Since $$|x_{m,i}-a_i|\leq \|x_m-a\|_1,$$
then $x_{m,i}\to a_i$. Conversely, suppose that $x_{m,i}\to a_i$ for all $i$. Since
$$\|x_{m}-a\|_1=\sum_{i=1}^n|x_{m,i}-a_i|,$$
then $x_m\to a$.

Comment: Could you elaborate how is the first inequality true?

Comment: Ah from $|| \cdot ||$ we can apply $C-S$ on the first inequality right?

Comment: @Daniel: Not at all. If $a,b>0$, then $a<a+b$ is always true...

Comment: I see! Could this be proved using the Euclidean norm?

Comment: @Daniel: All norms on $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent. If the convergence hold for the $1-$norm, then it converges for the $2-$norm as well.